# Html Conditional PageBreak

Tags: html, css, orphan

I have html page that generate report it contains sections and sub-sections. 
 Code has many tables and sub tables and div tags.
I want to apply page break when any section heading reach the end of the page.
Specifically "don't want heading at the end of the page while printing"

Comment: Which markup are you using, and what is the exact condition for page break? “When any section heading reach the end of the page” is vague formulation. In any case, the solution must be in CSS, not HTML, but the CSS code needed depends on the HTML markup used.

Comment: -1: So... what have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Tried the [CSS `orphans` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/orphans) already?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use specific page break, when printing, you can set this with CSS like the following :

CSS :

```
@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

HTML :

```
<!-- any content -->
<div class='page-break'></div>
```

By doing this you'll manually break the page at this tag.